# Reconstruct Riemannian Manifold with Measurements

Tags: differential-geometry, stochastic-processes, riemannian-geometry, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Suppose I have a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I can observe Brownian motions on it at some reasonable timescale; that is, I can observe $\hat{X}_{i,t}$ as a sequence of discrete positions over time $\hat{X}_{i,t}=\{\hat{X}_{i,0},\hat{X}_{i,\delta}, \ldots\}$ i.e. each being samples at sampling frequency $\delta$ on the continuous path of the $i$the Brownian motion trajectory.

We know that any of these observed motions were generated by an SDE describing an Ito diffusion process:
$$
dX_t^i = \sigma^i_j(X_t)dB^j_t +\frac{1}{2}b^i(X_t)dt
$$
(e.g. see Hsu, A Brief Introduction to Brownian
Motion on a Riemannian Manifold), where $\sigma$ and $b$ depend on $g$, and here $i$ is referring to a component of the Brownian motion.

Is there a way to determine $\sigma$ and $b$ from these measurements? Or, even better, to determine $g$?

Comment: This seems like a great question. It might be better suited for MathOverflow, but this is not my field, so I can't say.

Comment: @MikeMiller thanks for the suggestion; I'll try that if nothing shows up here after awhile